# Granting of permission by api fails if it's very fast, after project creation

Tags: sonarqube

I'm implementing the automation of project creation in Sonarqube 7.1.

When using the endpoint `/api/projects/create` , I add the project successfully and it returns 200.

```
POST /api/projects/create HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9000
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 4f1da833-85fa-74c4-90a3-ae0054003199

project=0001_proj_0002&name=Project+Test+2
```

Next I then use the endpoint `/api/permissions/add_user` to add the permission to a user, it returns
204 as expected, but does not properly update the project.

```
POST /api/permissions/add_user HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9000
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 93508e26-1dd7-9ef8-c1b4-96a064e76e27

projectKey=0001_proj_0002&login=login_client%40gmail.com&permission=admin
```

If between these two endpoin, I sleep for 5 seconds, it works correctly.

Am I doing something wrong?
Has anyone ever experienced this?

Comment: When you say "but does not properly update the project", what do you mean ? How do you check the state of the project ?

Comment: If you select the project that was created and then go to permissions the user is not added to the user list for that project.

Comment: Could you please specify the parameters you're using with api/permissions/add_user ? Maybe you're using it on the wrong project.

Comment: I put the parameters I used, but I believe they are correct, because if I wait about 5 seconds between each request, it works correctly.

Comment: Hum, it's strange indeed. Maybe you could try to use DEBUG mode on server's log and see what happen just after adding the permission.